# Assign a list of elements to become the attributes of a class instance in another list

Tags: python, excel

I use data from an excel sheet to create a list, that I'd like to unpack to become the attributes of a class instance using *.

```
import openpyxl

class rowData: 
    def __init__(self, segment=None, country=None, product=None, discountBand=None, unitsSold=None, manufacturingPrice=None, salePrice=None, grossSales=None, discounts=None, sales=None, COGS=None, profit=None, date=None, monthNumber=None, monthName=None, year=None):
        self.segment            = segment
        self.country            = country
        self.product            = product
        self.discountBand       = discountBand
        self.unitsSold          = unitsSold
        self.manufacturingPrice = manufacturingPrice
        self.salePrice          = salePrice
        self.grossSales         = grossSales
        self.discounts          = discounts
        self.sales              = sales
        self.COGS               = COGS
        self.profit             = profit
        self.date               = date
        self.monthNumber        = monthNumber
        self.monthName          = monthName
        self.year               = year
```

I have a list of 10 class instances, and a function that creates a list of the data from the Excel sheet's i-th row:

```
properList = []
for i in range(10):
    properList.append(rowData(i))

def createListforRow(i):
    newList = []
    for cell in sheet[i]:
        convertToString = str(cell.value)
        newList.append(convertToString)
    return newList
```

I've successfully done the following, to unpack `testList` to be attributes of a single class instance `exampleClassInstance`.

```
testList = createListforRow(2)
exampleClassInstance = rowData(*testList)
```

But I cannot make it work when I try to unpack directly into the class instance in `properList`e.g.

```
testList = createListforRow(2)
properList[0] = (*testList)
```

As I get:

```
    properList[0] = (*testList)
                     ^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: cannot use starred expression here
```

Ideally, I would be able to call `createListforRow` repeatedly, and assign that list to be the attributes of any `rowData` class instance in `properList`

The data I am using is as follows:
[Microsoft Financial Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mnDZq.png)

Answer (score 0):

The star (*) expression is used to pass several arguments at once to a constructor, like instantiating a class in your example. You cannot build a list like in your code. You can do something like:

```
properList = list(testList)
```

if you want a copy of the list. I however recommend that you not create a class for this. Just used a [named_tuple](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple)